# How to use Tamil language in my website?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have installed the [language selection page](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_selection_page) module. I have *Tamil*, *English* language to be chosen by users.

If user chooses *English* means site will appear in *English* Language. If user chooses *Tamil* language means site will appear in *Tamil* language.

So, how can I install *Tamil* language in Drupal 7.34?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module to make your site multi language. It gives you translate interface for every language you select in configuration.

After enabling the module you have to add *Tamil* as language under `admin/config/regional/language/add`.